# Как получить значение с помощью атрибута name

Tags: javascript, dom

Для реализации одной задачи нужно "вытянуть" из тега `<p>` значение не с помощью атрибута `id`, а с помощью `name`, но у меня никак не получается это сделать. По разному пробовал: или ошибка выскакивает, или `undefined`.

```js
alert(document.my_form.list.example_1);
```

```html
<form name="my_form">
  <ol name="list">
    <li name="example_1">2*12</li>
    <li name="example_2">2*11</li>
    <li name="example_3">2*10</li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `document.getElementsByName()`. Подробнее тут: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Answer (score 1):

Как написал выше @AlexChermenin, получить элементы по имени можно через `document.getElementsByName()`.

Конкретно в вашем примере можно написать следующим образом:

```js
alert(document.getElementsByName("example_1")[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<form name="my_form">
  <ol name="list">
    <li name="example_1">2*12</li>
    <li name="example_2">2*11</li>
    <li name="example_3">2*10</li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

В данном фрагменте кода мы получаем все элементы страницы с `name="example_1"`. Т.к. в примере всего один элемент с таким атрибутом, то можем сразу выбрать первый элемент массива `[0]` и дальше произвести действие. В этом примере с помощью `.innerHTML` забрал у элемента содержимое. Если элементов с одинаковыми атрибутами и одинаковыми значениями атрибутов несколько, то необходимо дополнительно проводить проверку при переборе массива, на пример по `id`, `class` или иным атрибутам.

Comment: Большое спасибо, а то я уже начал разбираться с 'getElementsByName()' и тут как раз возникла проблемка, Вы ее решили ;)